# How to autosave images on F12 render?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, saving

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>F12</kbd> to render animation Blender outputs images to folder. That's nice.

But it fails to do that when I press  <kbd>F12</kbd>. It's very annoying when - for example - I want to manually re-render couple of frames that were broken for some reason when rendering full animation.

Sure, I can manually save them, but I have to input frame name and that makes it error-prone and annoying. Sure I can change animation range to do this, but that's also annoying. I know I can write a script to render whatever frames I want, but that's also a bit of work that I hope could be avoided.

Comment: Hi :). The *File Output* node in compositor works well for me. And outputs the frame number like you need.

Comment: I don't get why this question was closed - it differs from the one asked in link and because of that correct answer is different. Even if answer is somewhere there I believe this deserves it's own Q&A.